# How to apply an option to several figures at the same time

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I do this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=[1,2,3]
b=[3,4,5]

plt.figure(1)
plt.xlim(0,3)
plt.plot(b)
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(a)
plt.show()
```

the choice of the x axes will be applied only to figure 1. What can I use to discriminate between the options that I want to be valid for only figure 1 or 2 and the ones that I want to be applied to both figures?

Clarification: I know that it is possible to call `plt.xlim` several times. I was rather looking for some command of a form like

```
plt.apply_options_to(1,2)
```

and from that moment on every time I call `plt.xlim` the option is applied to both figures and not only one of the two.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please be more specific

Comment: They want to apply the x limits to both Figure 1 and Figure 2 in one call to `plt.xlim()`

Comment: With pyplot each command applies to the currently active figure or axes. Just add another `plt.xlim(0,3)` below `plt.figure(2)`. In general I would recommend using the object oriented approach instead of pyplot.

Comment: I clarified what I need to do. T.Y.
@ImportanceOfBeingErnest I would like to do it in a single command. T.Y.

Comment: What does "a single command" mean? Is it something that can be written in a single line? Maybe you can state the motivation behind all this, such that one can find the best possible solution for you?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Correct, written in a single line. I might want to make several figures that differ in few aspects and have many aspects in common. I would like to avoid to repeat all the choices for every figure (axes, legends etc.etc.) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pyplot, each command applies to the currently active figure or axes. This means you can easily loop over the figures and apply each command like

```
for i in (1,2):
    plt.figure(i)
    plt.xlim(0,3)
```

Now those are three lines of code. If the requirement is to use a single line of code, the following would be a solution

```
[plt.setp(plt.figure(i).axes[0], xlim=(0,3)) for i in plt.get_fignums() if i in (1,2)]
```

This is neither elegant nor easy to type, so when using pyplot I would recommend the first solution.

In general however I would recommend using the object oriented approach, where creating two figures would look like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=[1,2,3]
b=[3,4,5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(b)
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.plot(a)

plt.show()
```

Then the single line solution is also a bit more compact

```
plt.setp([ax,ax2], xlim=(0,3))
```

Comment: Good, the object oriented approach seem the most elegant and most practical to use. t.y.